# Perl one liner to search and print a specific value from a file

Tags: perl

Need a one liner Perl script that will open a file and return a string.
I use a Perl script to compile c# code for my developers.
The solution file project.sln file may contain:

- Visual Studio 2005 
  or
- Visual Studio 2008 
  or
- Visual Studio 2010

Depending on the VS version, I need to load the appropriate VS environment and proceed to compiling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Perl version of `grep`, except it only needs to look for the first line that contains Visual Studio 20xx and return the 20xx value?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
while (<>)
{
    if (m/Visual Studio (2\d\d\d)\b/)
    {
        print "$1\n";
        exit 0;
    }
}
exit 1;
```

I suppose that doesn't meet the 'one-liner' criterion.  If you forego the exit statuses and live with multiple version numbers if the string appears multiple times, you can compress that to:

```
perl -n -e 'print $1 if (m/Visual Studio (2\d\d\d)\b/);' project.sln
```

Note that I've set you up for a Y3K problem with the regex I use - you'll have to decide whether to replace the 2 with another '`\d`'.

Comment: "a Y3K problem" - Now _that's_ optimism.

Comment: @Ashley: you'd be surprised at how long software lasts!  I'm on record that I plan to start work on the Y10K problem on 5000-01-02 (or, more accurately, I don't plan to start work on it before then).  I suspect it may never reach the top of my ToDo list, therefore.

Comment: Even just `perl -n -e 'print $1 if (m/foo/);' file.txt` is empty for me, even though file.txt definitely contains `foo`.

Comment: @NHDaly: Note where the parentheses are in the examples in the answer.  They're part of the regular expression, and are a capture group — they're not around the match regular expression.  When you match just `m/foo/`, there is no capture, so `$1` isn't set, so you get nothing printed. If you used `perl -lne 'print $1 if m/(foo)/;' file.txt`, you should get a `foo` printed for each line that matches.  (The `-l` handles newlines automatically; without it, you get a `foo` printed without any newline for each appearance in the file.)

Answer (score 0):

```
type project.sln | perl -pe "s/Visual Studio //"
```

Or do you need something other than the version?